# Neutral, science-based Undead

Tags: creature-design, immortality, bio-mechanics, vampires, adaptability

I'm looking for one or more biological processes that could be bolstered, changed, or introduced to a human to create a severely extended lifespan, ideally requiring death first, in order to best mimic the category of 'undead' creatures one sees in popular fantasy. Ideally, this process would also mangle the undead person's appearance and produce the classic undead drives of blood/flesh/brains, but these are a want rather than a must-have. The most important quality is that the process be relatively believable as a near-future process given what we know about science today.

Comment: Is your setting sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: TL;DR: A little of both. Longer answer, it's post-post apoc in which a massive accidental nuclear conflict created a tear between realities. We have some limited access to magic, and some limited access to near-future (minor AI, beginnings of transhumanism).

Comment: so psuedo shadowrun, good enough :)

Comment: How precisely do you define "undead"? What makes this an undead issue rather than "how do I make people live forever or at least extremely long lifespans with little susceptibility to disease but a slight tendency to crave a more meat-based diet"?

Comment: The undead are usually evil because they kill without hesitation. Either because they are summoned that way and made loyal to their master, or because they only have animalic instincts left.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi I'm throwing them in the undead bucket because I'm trying to play on most of the general undead tropes on the fluff side. Just like the other side in a war isn't necessarily evil, just having a different set of priorities, care about their needs above yours, etc, I'm trying to give all factions motivations and culture beyond 'rar, I do it because I'm evil, and that's what evil things do!' The actual state of undeadedness is of less concern.

Comment: @Chris then your question is rather unclear about what you are asking for. If you want undead, you're going to need to know what undead means, and how that is different than if these were just people who figured out a way to use genetic engineering to eliminate senescence. The nature of how things are undead is rather fundamental to your question of how to achieve a state of being undead. Else, if undead is irrelevant to you, you just don't want them mindlessly evil, then just don't make them mindlessly evil.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi That's why I defined my terms clearly in my post, rather than leave the definition up to the reader. I want a mostly-scientific way to create an undead-like condition to fit my story goals.

Comment: @Chris sorry I'm not more clear - how do you define an "undead-like condition"? Before being able to find a path to "undead", we need to know the destination - what is "undead"? Is it an animated corpse where magic provides the motive force to an otherwise rotting body while trans-dimensional intelligence controls it like a puppet? Do they still have hearts pumping and nerves firing and a functioning metabolism such that they are indistinguishable but for cultural convention calling them undead because they used antibiotics to cure an otherwise fatal infection? Define "alive" and "undead".

Comment: Your use of "undead" is really, really, really confusing - because it brings with it a whole truckload of baggage: everything from looks to behavior.  You keep saying "undead," but you seem to mean "immortal so long as they take care of themselves."  You've gotta find a better word.  In the meantime, I want you to rent and watch two movies: *Death Becomes Her* starring Meryl Streep, Goldie Hawn, and Bruce Willis; and *The Age of Adeline* starring Blake Lively and Harrison Ford.  I especially recommend *Adeline,* which specifically (fictionally) explains her immortality.

Comment: I think a large part of the disconnect is that I'm coming to y'all for crunch, because y'all put questions on hold if people ask for fluff. I am utilizing as many undead tropes and cliches as I can in the portrayal of this faction: the venerable lich with a tenuous grasp on his humanity, the mindless hordes of zombies, the conflicted-but-driven vampire, the revenant left behind to wander eternity alone. Rather than just handwave them away as 'magic did it', I find that people are more likely to dig deeper into the reasons 'why' if there's some detail under the hood. (Continued)

Comment: @JBH The actual details of how someone became in this unnatural state is less important to me than the fact that there are details there that make sense. If someone feels they have a whole picture of a situation, they are more likely to feel comfortable making a value decision on their own. So you are correct in that I'm not being as discerning about whether this faction are fulfilling all the checkboxes for what we consider undead today, in part because if I checked all the checkboxes, I'd end up at an always-evil creature, but also in part because it's the story that's more important to me.

Comment: I was dissapointed.  I came here to talk about structural integrity of building materials and how to construct a real life dam out of the bodies of the undead.  Can't you see the construction of the Hoover Dam with Bruce Campbell supplying the building materials from his hunting shack on the canyon rim?

Comment: Chris - I'm somewhat confused as to what you are asking - it seems that the post deals with (at least) two related but separate questions: 1.**Creature-Design science based undead**: your comments mention several very different archetypes (zombies, lich, vampire, revenant). Some near-future tech *and* magic are allowed, and a common origin for them all is required. - this can probably be split into 4 different sub-questions linked together, or at least, a different question than #2 (see next comment).

Comment: 2. **Psychology: Are Classic Non-evil Undead Possible?** - on one hand, you want to check as many check-boxes of the classical tropes - zombies are mindless and crave brains, The Lich is so old and obsessed he is losing his grasp on his humanity, etc. etc. The classic tropes usually make the undead indisputably evil - either because of their behavior (zombies wants to kill and eat you, The Lich see you as a pawn or a mere nuisance to be swatted like a bug, a vampire will kill you for food, or enslave you to his will - all of these are hard to morally defend). OR ...

Comment: ... OR the undead very nature makes them evil: they are meat puppets under the control of malign demons. Or, souls exist and as long as an undead flesh walks, the soul of the deceased is tormented in this/another dimension, etc. etc. Looks like you are asking how to get the classic tropes **without** the evil component. This sounds like a separate question, and it's unclear what's blocking you from just skipping the "evil" check-boxes. Consider to split and edit these to get better answers.

Comment: @G0BLiN I've learned my lesson about asking about fluff. I am decidedly NOT asking whether they can be non-evil. The only reason I mention the fluff at all is to give context to those who asked for it while complaining that my undead weren't undead enough. So no, I'm not splitting this.

Comment: @adaliabooks If you pay attention to my actual question up-top, it does not mention any fluff topics. I was not aware that the comments were considered part of the question.

Comment: @Chris I think the edited version is far clearer, I've withdrawn my close vote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Telomere-therapy

The [telomere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere) is basically a protective layer for genes that prevents them from being truncated during cell division. After some time the telomeres are truncated so much that the genes will get truncated next - which means that the body dies. Theoretically by [lengthening the telomeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere#Lengthening) you could achieve immortality - or at least very, very long life.

If you simply add that in your setting the not-yet found mechanism to lengthen telomeres requires certain... adaptations... to the human body you could have your non-evil undead. Perhaps each time the telomeres are lengthened your human loses some parts of what makes them *human*.

You used the [vampires](/questions/tagged/vampires) tag, so possibly the therapy would include drinking human blood to use something in the blood as a catalyst or building block for the lengthening process. Over time the people are getting used to it. They also get special medicine so that they can safely drink as much human blood as they need - or want.

In the end it's still a lengthening - not necessarily true immortality.

The very, very long lifespan might also have an impact on their brain. You probably don't know everything that happened when you were five or six - and just like you forgot about those years, your human would slowly start to forget about the ages twenty to one-hundred-thirty. The ones who focus on blending into society would be able to adapt - but some of them would become weird because they try to stay in the past or because life gets so fast that they can't keep up, just like a year was *endless* as a little child and is far too fast as an adult.

In the end, some of them might seem braindead - if they don't take care. But that's their fault - nothing evil to see, just humans neglecting their own mental health.

Comment: There's also the fact that telomere shortening isn't the only process behind aging. If you focus on the telomeres, things like NAD+ (a co-enzyme used in metabolism) and stem cell deficiency start wreaking havoc, and, lo and behold, you have a scientific reason to crave the flesh/blood/brains of the living!

Comment: Related to this, and pretty applicable to the question in general: "[Film Theory: The REAL Reason Wolverine is DYING!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viOpP6P_PrQ)" might be of interest.

Comment: Just for scientific completeness, the reason we have these self destruct timers on cells is due to cancer. In a human body old age/caner are kind of  2 extremes and we have evolved to be somewhere in the middle. So this may be a problem if not also treated magically

Comment: @NoName I have not heard about stem cell deficiency. Aren't they, by definition, a part of an immortal cell line? I could be wrong. Additionally, all the other cell deficits are caused by telomeres' shortening at the end of the day.

Comment: @Andrey I think that could be solved by using a feature the the lobsters use: they slightly increase in size by molting and that reduces the chances of cancerous growth. In fact, at one point this large size is the cause of higher probability of death for the lobsters.

Comment: I'll plump for this answer but I'd alter it to suggest that: (1) Death (and complete chilling of body) is the mechanism that inactivates the normal enzymes that deal with telomeres (they are permanently  inactivated by cold) and (2) immortality itself is what leads to evil (a la *Altered Carbon.*) While one could poke holes in this, easily, it is also a good start for an idea.

Comment: @KaviVaidya Telomere lengthening might keep stem cells from getting depleted (and they do get depleted, aging causes the stem cells to get used up faster than they can be replaced), but I don't think NAD+ deficiency depends on telomere length. More likely it's caused by accumulated mutations, the same things that cause cancer and cell senescence (basically Cancer Lite, the cells don't divide like crazy, but they don't self-destruct either, and cause other kinds of harm).

Answer (score 12):

**Parasite**.

- The fungus *Ophiocordyceps* controls ants so they climb down, when they reach the final position, the fungus forces them to stop and the fungi invades the ant completely.
- *Toxoplasma gondii* is a parasite invading mice so that they lose the fear of cats and, gulp, the cat is happy. Unfortunately it seems also to invade the cat and **it is suspected that they also can invade the human host, causing the *cat lady* syndrome**.
- *Xenos vesparum* attacks wasps and forces them to retract from their social duties and fly to specific destinations.

So, your brain parasite infiltrates the human brain. It reproduces by invading the human, so that bites and scratches can infect other humans. Because the brain is not longer needed, the parasite can also shut off the warm-bloodedness and slow down the metabolim extremely, leading to an extended energy reservoir (in fact most of our energy is needed to hold 37 °C temperature), very limited breathing, no detectable infrared radiation and undetectable pulse. They are "undead", but very much "alive" if a chance to infect another human is given. The crave for flesh is simply a byproduct of the infection. If no food can be gathered, the parasite extend lifetime by searching a cold place and going into an very long hibernation, it does not care if the human flesh rots.

Comment: I was about to answer this question by talking about the same parasites, but yours is so good that I don't think I need to add anything.

Answer (score 9):

**Golem body**

You could fulfill your first 2 criteria by having a human mind in an artificial body.  You side step death and decay that way.

Robot bodies are not uncommon in SF.  If you tend towards the fantasy you could have a body like a golem: clay or stone, possessed by the spirit / mind of a person whose body was dead.

1:  Without flesh to decay, the mind is immortal (if you want it to be).

2:  The body would not decay because it is not meat.  It might need a touchup with new clay now and again.

3:  Re craving flesh - maybe there are deficits inherent in a clay body that make the mind in it feel strange irresistible cravings.  Instead of flesh (it has been done so much!) you could have the artificial creature crave salt, which seems more golemy somehow.  Blood has a lot of salt...

Comment: Or, if you want the flesh clichè and still use "golems", you could look at mister Frankenstein and create a *flesh* golem - which means you regularly need new *parts* to keep your body *fresh*.

Comment: That is a great twist @Secespitus.  A better way of meeting criterion #3.

Comment: Frankenstein's monster is also one of the finest examples of an undead thing which is not evil.

Comment: @Secespitus nice!  that is a really cool concept.

Answer (score 5):

Conservation of energy seems to me to be the big one.  While you can make zombies which eat an acceptable diet, most of them are depicted as eating a little meat here and there, and most are too slow to catch their prey.  If energy was no longer a fundamental limit, all sorts of strange things occur.  Perhaps these magical zombies have a limit to power instead of energy -- they only get so many kJ/day from whatever magical source keeps them alive.

Consider the parable of [Two Wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Wolves), typically attributed to the Cherokee.

> A grandfather is talking with his grandson and he says there are two wolves inside of us which are always at war with each other.
>
> One of them is a good wolf which represents things like kindness, bravery and love. The other is a bad wolf, which represents things like greed, hatred and fear.
>
> The grandson stops and thinks about it for a second then he looks up at his grandfather and says, “Grandfather, which one wins?”
>
> The grandfather quietly replies, the one you feed

Imagine if you lived to this parable all your life, not feeding the bad wolf.  The bad wolf is constantly limited by starvation, and yet it persists.  As the parable mentions, the two wolves are constantly at war, and merely not feeding one doesn't change that.  Now imagine one day that starvation limitation was lifted.  It could be a conscious choice, or a spontaneous discovery of a new energy source, or even magic.  Maybe the bad wolf just found a way to burrow into the good wolf's food stash.  It doesn't really matter.  Now you have a wolf that, all it's life has learned to contend with the good wolf while starving, and it suddenly is not starving anymore.

That leads all sorts of places now, doesn't it?

Comment: Really cool idea.  I'd like to read that story!

Answer (score 3):

To my eyes, you are describing a vampire.

Vampires have:

- immortality: check
- slow or no decay: check
- classic undead drives: check

Now notice that vampirism isn't necessarily a choice. In most literatures, it is forced upon a person, usually in very traumatic ways. You have an intelligent creature that drinks blood in order to survive - doing evil things is entirely optional.

One might say that they should have at least some basic human rights. So they need some blood here and there... But hey, blood donation is a thing. Or maybe they can get it from animals. For a well-meaning vampire, it is only when access to these is negated or non-existing that they will turn to violence against humans.

A lot of twists can be made out of these. They might be [an accident from science, that secretly fight to protect the innocent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morbius,_the_Living_Vampire). Or they might openly be [humanity's last hope against something worse](http://lastblood.keenspot.com/). In either case some moral ambiguity will exist - keeping them from feeding will cause the death of innocents.

---

As to the changes necessary to make someone a vampire: take [Secespitus answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/107901/21222), add furhter genetic alterations to include regeneration abilities (take some genes from salamanders or some other animal), and optionally add genes for [porphyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria), the "vampire" disease as well. The genes might be inserted into one's own genome by using some sort of [adenovirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenoviridae) that is transmissible through bodily fluids (i.e.: injecting a vampire's saliva into a victim's blood).

Heavy exsanguination of the victim is necessary in order for its immunological system not to kill the virus, and once the virus has done its job the regeneration kicks in and "ressurects" the victim as a new vampire.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can have a 'one-size fits all' answer to traditional undead. To start with there are a number of very different creatures you could call undead; liches, vampires, zombies and ghosts would appear to be the main categories.

A Lich is basically just a human who cannot die. There might be some kind of madness involved but they are generally just seen as humans who have found a method to cheat death (though not necessarily ageing).
First obvious answer has already been covered by Willk - robot bodies with human minds transferred into them.
The second answer is human bodies with minds transferred into them. Either clones of the original person or other bodies depending on the desired result. This provides a still living being that would age and decay, and possibly die if the lich doesn't upload their mind in time and place it in a new body. Or you could say the lich keeps a backup of their minds somewhere so even if their current body dies it is not the end of their existence. This also ties in with the idea of soul jars where a piece of the soul is kept to preserve the lich's life.

Vampires... are more complicated. Genetic experiment gone wrong seems the most likely. Increased speed, strength and regenerative capabilities but needs something in blood to survive or fuel those abilities. Similarly you could say they are robotic or cyborgs, an early model that required blood to fuel themselves.

Zombies tend to be mindless, so some kind of bacterial or fungal infection that reanimates a dead body and gives it locomotion and drive without in anyway restoring the mind.
If you wanted to stick with the theme of the liches you could say they are failed attempts, people whose minds became corrupted in the transfer and whose clone bodies failed and began to decay while still 'alive'. Maybe they are what liches become after they have transferred their minds too many times and gathered too many small errors in the process.

Ghosts are difficult too. If we stick with the theme of immortality through mind uploading then ghosts could be minds stuck in computers. Perhaps they have holographic bodies or maybe they can just control a futuristic set of smart household devices (turning lights on and off, operating kitchen appliances etc. typically haunting behaviour).

If you want to have a variety of undead and a central theme that ties them together than I believe you start with the drive to achieve immortality through the transfer of consciousness and work from there. Whether you want robotic bodies or grown clone humans depends on the kind of setting you want.

Answer (score 3):

A highly specific cancer.

Cancer has the potential to grant everlasting life if we can control it. If a cancer somehow manages to renew all parts of the body, including the brain, you have the everlasting life part. If this regeneration process is imperfect on parts of the brain you can lose functionality such as knowing what food is good for you.
The body already locks down and isolates cancers of the body in "birth"marks. Magnify this to the body isolating and rejecting finger-sized malignant growths that would otherwise wreck the body across the entire body, and that can temporarily cause parts of the bodies surface to starve and die off, only to regenerate haphazardly after the growth has literally been expelled of the body (which also would have a gross fase where it starts dying off). Now you have a continuously scarred, regenerating and on patches bleeding/dying skin fitting for an undead. Bonus is that even a neutral undead would still be confronted as a leper.

Ofcourse,.this cancer is 99.99% magic at that point, but this is the best sciency handwavium I could come up with.

Comment: Makes me think of Deadpool.

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible that [life is really old](https://www.nature.com/news/life-possible-in-the-early-universe-1.14341). The temperature of background radiation was in the Goldilocks region only a few hundred million years after the Big Bang. And there is no guarantee that nothing exists beyond the cosmological event horizon - meaning there may be things from outside the blast radius of the Big Bang that work their way in.

With most of the 4.5 billion year life of the observed universe, or with the uncountable amount of time that has passed outside the cosmological horizon, it is possible that some very strange things may have evolved out there [and come here](https://www.space.com/38846-space-dust-panspermia-alien-life.html) trapped in meteoric glass or as dust.

Human kind is an interesting species structurally. It begins as [three sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilaminar_blastocyst) of extremely different specialized cells: nervous, digestive, and skeletal/circulatory. It's almost as if the human species is three different species in a symbiotic relationship sharing one common genetic library.

But it doesn't end there : some of the most fundamental building blocks to all cellular life [don't come from the human genome at all](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~bioslabs/studies/mitochondria/mitorigin.html). In this strange world - mitochondria, an ancestor of ancient bacteria, provide power and proteins for most animal cells. The process by which ancient mitochondria may have invaded animal cells and settled there is called endosymbiosis.

It is possible that a similar bacteria-sized endosymbiote, maybe even one specialized for human kind, is in the environment, trapped in a glacier, recently arrived, or so on. This bacteria, specialized as it is, might not be capable of infecting a healthy cell.

During [apoptosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) and [autophagy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophagy), cells wind down their existences in an orderly fashion, taking apart the nucleus and inner workings of the cell before giving up. However, when animal cells die due to injury ([necrosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necrosis)) the cell struggles and eventually fails to hold it's inner workings against the forces of osmotic pressure. During this time the cell membrane begins to fall apart in pieces as it is compromised. This might even be how mitochondria originally entered animal cells. And our hypothetical specialist bacteria may be able to come in and set up shop.

Mitochondria quickly earn their keep providing cell energy and proteins. Endosymbiont X (for lack of a better term) may likewise help organize the dying shop. Maybe providing a great number of traits similar to [Tardigrades](https://www.nature.com/news/tardigrade-protein-helps-human-dna-withstand-radiation-1.20648), which include protection from starvation, dehydration, radiation, and shock. This might lead to the lungs being repurposed as a [hemocoel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulatory_system#Open_circulatory_system). A hemocoel might require filling from some of the classic undead foods.

Endosymbiont X might also be able to produce factors that protect telomeres from drop off. [Telomeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere) are the winding that protects DNA from unravelling, and is believed to correlate with cell life.

The new proteins could lead to structural changes in a human host, causing it to become deformed. Or, cell takeup of Endosymbiont X, as it depends on some pretty optimistic timing, might leave a good portion of the human actually dead, until those parts drop off or are removed.

Answer (score 3):

The zombie uses live cells for self repair by first converting the consumed cells into a stem cell.  This cell is then used for self repair.

Zombies prefer [flesh](https://www.cnn.com/2017/02/09/health/embryo-skin-cell-ivg/index.html) and brains because those cells are easy to convert to the required replacement cell.

These zombies are [normally slow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063350/).  But, if they are heavily damaged, the zombie goes into a [feeding frenzy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289043/).

[The answer by @Thorsten S](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/108216/21222) describes how one is turned into a zombie.  I'm only describing why they eat what they eat.

Answer (score 1):

They are parasites that populate the outside of a creature's skeleton in my novel. Liches are basically the queen, a matured parasite, so liches can raise walking skeletons.
They can also populate the inside of an armor, giving birth to walking armors. They form complex imitated muscle system to give the appearance of a walking person, however they are slower and more rigid.
Ghosts are consciousness formed by time paradoxes, in another dimension, projected into our world. It's the answer to "what if I go back in time and kill my grandfather". Time and dimension get confused and they continued to project the person as living, but they are actually dead.

Comment: Welcome to worlbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, pleast take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.